Sci-fi book about humanity warring against aliens that eliminate all species in the galaxy
I am looking for a book that I read last(?) year. I think it was rather older, though.
Aliens have arrived in some sort of ark, looking like a huge meteorite. At first they appear peaceful but then it is found out that they control the whole galaxy and eliminate all other species. Humanity leaves Earth and hides amongst the stars and, over thousands of years in which the human race evolves quite a lot, tries to fight back and take the fight to the aliens.
The aliens told the humans they were interested in religion and were journeying towards the end of time (I think) but it was a ruse and their ark harbored some kind of wormhole endpoint through which their spaceships came.

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

I read it last year I think but I think it was older. I don't remember the cover. The aliens told the humans they were interested in religion and were journeying towards the end of time (I think) but it was a ruse and their ark harbored some kind of wormhole endpoint through which their spaceships came

This is Salvation by Peter F. Hamilton.
The PFH wiki describes the main antagonist species thusly;

The Olyix believe that the universe is in a cycle of death and
rebirth. At the end of the current universe, all beings will coalesce
into the God at the End of Time. The Olyix believe that this event is
billions of years in the future, yet each Olyix hopes to live and
travel until they meet the God and join with it.
The largest Olyix ships are the arkships, gigantic vessels made out of
the remains of the Olyix home system's planets. Most arkships resemble
huge cylindrical asteroids around 45 kilometers long. They use huge
antimatter-based engines to travel on interstellar journeys, posing as
peaceful nomads and ingratiating themselves with a target civilization
before launching a surprise attack.



This was certainly my first thought when I read the description.

Yes that's the one, thank you very much!

@Aemon - Don't forget to upvote and mark this as accepted.
